# How to find out if lexicon exists before adding a custom pronunciation

Tags: c#

I am writing a text to speech application. I already have a pls file where I specified custom pronunciation for some words. Before applying my custom pronunciation, I need a code to show if a word already have a pronunciation. If the pronunciation exist for a word, do nothing, else use my pls file and apply custom pronunciation.

```
        try
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer SpeechSynthesizer2 = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            SpeechSynthesizer2.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            SpeechSynthesizer2.AddLexicon(new Uri("C:\\Users\\tm\\Desktop\\BibleFolderLocation\\BibleProject\\BibleProject\\lexicon.pls"), "application/pls+xml");
            // I want to know if the word Nnabuike which is already in my pls file already has has a pronunciation before applying a custom pronunciation for it.
            SpeechSynthesizer2.Speak("Nnabuike");
            // Remove the lexicon.  
            SpeechSynthesizer2.RemoveLexicon(new Uri("C:\\Users\\tm\\Desktop\\BibleFolderLocation\\BibleProject\\BibleProject\\lexicon.pls"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: We need more information. Do you have some kind of index in memory? Code snippets would help.

Comment: I added a code. May be it will help you to understand what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the .pls files are just XML files that contain the lexicon

Here is the sample from the Microsoft documentation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

<lexicon version="1.0"   
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/01/pronunciation-lexicon"  
      alphabet="x-microsoft-ups" xml:lang="en-US">  

  <lexeme>  
    <grapheme> blue </grapheme>  
    <phoneme> B L I P </phoneme>  
  </lexeme>  

</lexicon>
```

Now that we know they are XML files, you could deserialize them into objects to use, or use something like XDocument search them.

```
    string wordToFind = "blue";

    // load the XML document
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load("lexicon.pls");

    // search for nodes with the value you are looking for
    var found = xdoc.Descendants()
        .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "grapheme")
        .Where(x => x.Value.Trim().ToUpper() == wordToFind.ToUpper())
        .ToList();

    // use the count to find out if the word exists in the lexicon
    if (found.Count == 0)
    {
        // nothing found for the word blue 
        // load custom file
    }
```

Comment: PS: Welcome to StackOverflow. Don't forget to mark this as the answer if applicable.